# Why is serializer not emitting JSON API spec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers

First of all this is with active_model_serializers version 0.10.2 in Rails 4.2.

I have an Article model with two serializers for different scenarios but for this test they are the exact same except for differing class names, ArticleSerializer and ArticleSimpleSerializer. I can't figure out how to get ArticleSimpleSerializer to emit JSON in the JSON API format outside of a controller.

Here's my initializer with global serializer config.

```
ActiveModelSerializers.config.adapter = :json_api
ActiveModelSerializers.config.jsonapi_resource_type = :singular
ActiveModelSerializers.config.key_transform = :unaltered
```

**What works:**

Rendering in a controller: 
These both output JSON API format with data, type, and attributes root keys. The first one automatically finds and uses ArticleSerializer

```
render status: :ok, json: @article
render status: :ok, json: @article, serializer: ArticleSimpleSerializer
```

Rendering outside of controller with default lookup: 
This will find ArticleSerializer and the output will have data, type, and attributes root keys.

```
ActiveModelSerializers::SerializableResource.new(article).to_json
```

**What Doesn't Work:**

Rendering outside of controller with ArticleSimpleSerializer:
This will *NOT* include data, type, or attributes root keys. The JSON will basically be what I would expect under the attributes key.

```
ArticleSimpleSerializer.new(article).to_json
```

How can I get ArticleSimpleSerializer to emil JSON API format outside of a controller?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify which serializer to use (among other options) with SerializableResource.

This gets me what I wanted.

```
ActiveModelSerializers::SerializableResource.new(article, serializer: ArticleSimpleSerializer).as_json
```